# Manipulating certain vlaues within a data.frame or matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

i've following issue using R.

let's assume i've a data.frame (or matrix) in this structure:

```
t(data.frame(
"t1"=c(NA,NA,23,44),
"t2"=c(16,14,26,34),
"t3"=c(17,6,40,12),
"t4"=c(21,0.8,41,0.25),
"t5"=c(23,0.2,43,6)))
```

which leads to following data.frame:

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
t1   NA   NA   23 44.00
t2   16 14.0   26 34.00
t3   17  6.0   40 12.00
t4   21  0.8   41  0.25
t5   23  0.2   43  6.00
```

My aim is to substitute the values in each column, when there **occurs a "value less 1"**, with the **last available "value greater 1"**. This should last even if the value rises above 1 again.

See the desired structure (changes in column 2 and 3):

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
t1   NA   NA   23 44.00
t2   16 14.0   26 34.00
t3   17  6.0   40 12.00
t4   21  6.0   41 12.00
t5   23  6.0   43 12.00
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: After transposing you don't have a data.frame, but a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new.df <- apply(old.df, 2,
                function (k) {
                  first <- which(k < 1)
                  if (length(first) == 0) return(k)
                  first <- first[[1]]
                  k[first:nrow(old.df)] <- k[[first - 1]]
                  k
               })
```

The corner case where this will break is if the first value in a column is less than one. But that is a corner case in your question and not just this code.

Comment: could you give me a hint, what woould be the solution, without the last condition "This should last even if the value rises above 1 again." an would lead to following results:
Hence for colum 4 should deliver the values: 44,34,12,12,6